# Exponential Models Help

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

- The volume of a substance, A, measured in cubic centimeters increases according to the exponential growth model $\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0.3A$, where $t$ is measured in hours.
- The volume of another substance, B, also measured in cubic centimeters increases at a constant rate of
  $1\ \mbox{cm}^{3}$ per hour according to the linear model $\frac{\mathrm{d}B}{\mathrm{d}t} = 1.$
- At $t = 0$, substance A has a volume $A\left(0\right) = 3$ and substance B has size $B\left(0\right) = 5$.

I got $3.4531$ using the equations $\frac{1}{0.3}log|\frac{A}{3}|= t$ and $B-5=t,$ is that correct?

Comment: Could you show the work you used to arrive at your two possible solutions.

Comment: I got $3.4531$ using the equations $\frac{1}{0.3}log|\frac{A}{3}|= t$ and $B-5=t.$

Comment: I am not sure how that helps you find $t$, did you use a numerical approximation?

Comment: Also, you edited your post so that it no longer states that your question is "when do the two fluids have the same volume?"

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @RyanK's answer, we have
$$t=-\frac{10}{3}\, W_{-1}\left(-\frac{9}{10\, e^{3/2}}\right)-5$$ and this is the only analytical solution.

If you cannot use Lambert function, you will need a numerical method and then a reasonable guess of the root.

Consider that you are looking for the zero of function
$$f(t)=3 e^{3 t/10}-t-5$$ for which
$$f'(t)=\frac{9}{10}\, e^{3 t/10}-1 \qquad \text{and}\qquad f''(t)=\frac{27}{100}\, e^{3 t/10} \quad >0 \quad \forall t$$
The first derivative cancels at
$$t_*=\frac{10}{3} \log \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)$$ which is a minimum; since
$$f(t_*)=-\frac{5}{3}-\frac{10}{3} \log \left(\frac{10}{9}\right) <0$$ build a Taylor series around $t_*$. This will give, as an approximation*,
$$f(t)=-\left(\frac{5}{3}+\frac{10}{3} \log \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)\right)+\frac{3}{20}
   \left(t-\frac{10}{3} \log
   \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)\right)^2+O\left(\left(t-\frac{10}{3} \log
   \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)\right)^3\right)$$ solve the quadratic and keep the largest root. This will give
$$t_0=\frac{10}{3} \left(\log \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)+\sqrt{1+2 \log
   \left(\frac{10}{9}\right)}\right)\approx 4.01896$$ which does not look too bad.

Now, using Newton method, we should have the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 4.01896 \\
 1 & 3.52114 \\
 2 & 3.45418 \\
 3 & 3.45305
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

For the Initial Value Problem, $\frac{dy}{dt} = ky$ with $y(0) = y_0$ we obtain the solution $$y = y_0e^{kt}$$
So for the two fluids we have (both in units of $cm^3$)
$$A = 3e^{0.3t}\space\text{ and }\space B = 5+t$$
So
\begin{align*}
A &= B\\
3e^{0.3t} &= 5+t\\
t &= -5+\frac{1}{-0.3}W\left(-0.3\cdot3e^{0.3\cdot(-5)}\right)
\end{align*}
where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). However this gives the negative $t$ value which satisfies this equation, a numerical approximation gives that the positive $t$ values is $t \approx 3.45305018$.